# miglayout question: column constraints

Tags: swing, miglayout

I have a miglayout for a window where one of the columns was specified as `grow` but I need to modify that so it basically means "grow, but limit to ___ pixels".

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is doable. Just set the maximum size for the column. In the following example

```
setLayout(
   new MigLayout(
      "", 
      "[89px][:89px:250px,grow][89px,grow]", 
      "[23px][23px][23px]"));
```

the second column has a preferred size of 89 pixels and max size of 250 pixels. It will stop growing at 250. The third column will continue growing.